# Как сменить "новую личность" в TOR автоматически?

Tags: node.js, windows, tor

На компьютер с windows установил TOR Browser, подключился к сети TOR.

Это делаю для получения информации с сайта (сделал чтобы puppeteer отправлял запросы через TOR).

Данный сайт очень быстро блокирует IP, и мне приходится заходить в TOR и нажимать "Новая личность" чтобы IP сменился.

Каким образом можно сделать смену "личности" в TOR через nodejs?

Либо чтобы IP (личность) в TOR изменялась сама каждые n минут?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь! Перерыв весь интернет но ничего не нашел что могло бы мне помочь :(

Answer (score 0):

Как настроить автоматическую смену IP нашел - [Ролик на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm_o7GmzlKw)

Хотелось бы еще сделать менять IP TOR можно было командой node.js